# Why connection is droping when I scan the ip with nmap?

Tags: networking, scanner, nmap

When scanning an IP in LAN its connection drops for seconds and nmap says the host might be down. Why this happens?

Comment: Your question doesn't really come off clear to me.  Welcome!

Comment: Please provide more detail, what commands did you run, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the internet connection drops it may be due to the router or firewall detecting excessive traffic coming from your machine. Use less agressive setting for nmap

```
nmap -T polite -sP 192.168.1.0/24
```

The flag you want to use is -T. There are other options besides "polite" and they can be found in nmap manual